# PrimeSense Failed to set USB interface Error

Tags: ros, openni, turtlebot, xtion, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an Asus Xtion Camera attached to my computer running ROS Groovy

So far I've installed

1. Openni_Camera binary ( http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera )
2. Openni_launch binary ( http://ros.org/wiki/openni_launch )
3. Openni SDK  ( http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/ )
4. PrimeSense Sensor Module for Openni ( https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/tree/unstable )

Everytime I run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

i get this error

```
    process[camera/depth/metric_rect-8]: started with pid [25941]
process[camera/depth/metric-9]: started with pid [25955]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.9-0precise-20130724-2255/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.2.1: Failed to set USB interface!

process[camera/depth/points-10]: started with pid [25972]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [25973]
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-12]: started with pid [25974]
[FATAL] [1376100229.602956199]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1376100229.605474045]: Service call failed!
[camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died
```

I can run samples from the openni sdk outside of ros sometimes like "SimpleViewer". Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. I just don't get it. It detects the device but can't set the USB interface...what gives?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72022/primesense-failed-to-set-usb-interface-error/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-09**:
Did you install `/55-primesense-usb.rules` to /etc/udev/rules.d? This file may be found here:  https://github.com/PrimeSense/Sensor/blob/unstable/Platform/Linux/Install/55-primesense-usb.rules )

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-09**:
dPackard, sorry, it failed 4 times when i tried to post. Fixed.

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-09**:
How to i install that file to /etc/udev/rules.d ?

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-09**:
If you installed the package via apt-get, tit is probably installed already (just check if the file exists). Otherwise you can create the file manually using your favorite text editor and `sudo`. (e.g. `sudo gvim /etc/udev/rules.d/55-primesense-usb.rules`).

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-09**:
Tried that, no luck. I appreciate your help though.

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-09**:
If that file already exists (or if creating it doesn't help), you might find a solution here: ( http://answers.ros.org/question/55201/using-ros-with-kinect-failed-to-set-usb-interface/ )

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-11**:
I went ahead and got a kinect. Still problems, just much less ;)

**Comment by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on 2014-02-14**:
Were you able to resolve the issue? I am using a Kinect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I experienced the same problem with the Xtion. It could be resolved by plugging the device into another, non USB3.0 compatible, USB port.

---

Originally posted by [Tones](https://answers.ros.org/users/3551/tones/) with karma: 635 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be using one of the newer Xtion cameras, which are not supported by OpenNI 1. For those versions use OpenNI 2, which is already supported by ROS (http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_camera, http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_launch).

To verify your version, do

```
$ lsusb
```

The older version are listed as

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1d27:0600
```

whereas the newer versions are listed as:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1d27:0601
```

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1